# What's the difference between deleting an eventhub and deleting a name space?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, namespaces, devops, azure-eventhub

Here is some confusion I have met.

For example, I have two event hub namespaces named A and B. A and B both contain a topic called C.

I want to know :

1. if I delete C in namespace A, will it affect namespace B?
2. if I delete namespace A, will it affect namespace B?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you do in one Azure EventHub namespace doesn't affect another namespace, each namespace provides a "unique scoping container" (including deleting a namespace).

Each Azure EventHub namespace (like a "folder") can contain many eventhubs (like "files" inside the parent "folder"), here is a good doc to get familiarized with the concepts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#namespace

Unless you specifically deployed an app or configured some sort of forwarding/connection between eventhubs ("C" in your case), there's no impact from deleting "C" from "A" unto "B" (or viceversa) by default.